# Following the logic behind this particular piece of basic JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

```
var james = {
    job: "programmer",
    married: false
};

// set to the first property name of "james"
var aProperty = "job";

// print the value of the first property of "james" 
// using the variable "aProperty"
console.log(james[aProperty]);
```

So first I create an object called James, I give it the properties of "job" and "married".
I then give those properties values of "programmer" and "false".

I create a variable called aProperty and set it equal to the name of the first property (which is supposed to be ready as property name - in that order). My question is on the last particular line:

What specifically is happening here? I am calling the object james and am I **passing** it a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What specifically is happening here? I am calling the object james and am I passing it a value?

Only functions can be called; the syntax `james[aProperty]` is [property access using the bracket notation](https://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1). It’s like dot notation, but accepts an expression to use as the name of the property instead of an identifier*.

<sub>* Identifier or keyword.</sub>